# MySql Trigger can't update MySql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table of box and box archive for this purpose I write triger which move data from box to box_archived table when user delete box and box archive table data update for this purpose I write following mysql trigger but when I delete box then I receive following error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1442 Can't update table 'box' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. (SQL: update `box` set `archive` = 1, `updated_at` = 2018-04-06 07:31:57 where `id` = 48116 and `user_id` = 87)
```

Below is my trigger code which i write in phpmyadmin MySql

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `move_archived_box`;CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `move_archived_box` AFTER UPDATE ON `box` FOR EACH ROW begin 
    insert into box_archived
        select * from box where archive = 1; 
    delete from box where archive = 1; 
 end;
```

I also run trigger only when only archive column is update

Comment: Error is clear - you cannot action the table which fired the trigger.